# Does This Inequality of Vector Norms Hold in General?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with finite dimension $n$, endowed with a norm $|| \cdot ||_X$. Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be a basis.

Does there exist a real $C$ (maybe just $C=1$) such that for any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and any $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, we have 
$$
||\alpha x_i + \beta x_j||_X 
\hspace{1mm}\geq\hspace{1mm}
C||\alpha x_i||_X?
$$
I know that in general, we certainly do *not* have $||a+b||_X \geq ||a||_X$ when $a,b \in X$. 
However, it's tempting to believe that when $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent (e.g., $a=\alpha x_i$, $b=\beta x_j$), that we may get something like this.
Is this only naive temptation, or is there hope? Thanks.

Comment: I presume you mean to include the constraint $C > 0$?

Comment: Yes. I suppose you're right that $C \leq 0$ would be a somewhat degenerate case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a finite dimensional normed linear space any linear function is continuous. Consider the map $L(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_jx_j)=a_ix_i$. Continuity of this map shows that $\|a_ix_i\| \leq M \|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_jx_j\|$ for some $M \in (0,\infty)$. Hence $\|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_jx_j\| \geq C \|a_ix_i\|$ where $C =\frac 1 M$.

Comment: Oh yeah! I just learned that theorem that every linear operator $X \to Y$ is bounded when $X$ has finite dimension, and that this is equivalent to being continuous.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would this generalize to $\dim(X) = \aleph_0$?. Maybe, $X=\mathbb{C}^{\aleph_0}$ for concreteness?

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman No, it is not true for infinite dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function

$$ f_j(\beta) = \frac{\|\alpha x_i + \beta x_j \|}{\|\alpha x_i\|}. $$

As $|\beta| \to \infty$ so does $f_j(\beta)$ as we can see by applying the reverse triangle inequality:

$$ \|\alpha x_i + \beta x_j \| \ge \Big| \|\alpha x_i\| - \|\beta x_j\| \Big| \ge |\beta| \|x_j\|, $$
where the last inequality holds as long as $\|\beta x_j\| > \|\alpha x_i\|$.

Therefore $f_j$ has a global minimum $C_j$. If $C = \min_{i\ne j}\{C_j\}$ then we have

$$ C \le C_j \le \frac{\|\alpha x_i + \beta x_j \|}{\|\alpha x_i\|} $$

for all $\beta$ and all $j$.

We should also note that $C_j > 0$ since $x_i$ and $x_j$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Wow, also a lovely idea. I see that $f_j(\beta)$ is positive for all $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$. Is the norm known to be continuous, though? I assume that is the result you are using to conclude that there exists a global minimum, but I may also simply misunderstand some detail.

Comment: Norms are continuous, yes (by the reverse triangle inequality: $\Big|\|x\| - \|y\|\Big| \le \|x - y\|$). We need to know $f_j(\beta) \to \infty$ as $|\beta| \to \infty$ so we can say that, for example, there is some $R$ such that if $|\beta| > R$ then $f_j(\beta) \ge f_j(0)$. Then we minimize over the compact set $|\beta| \le R$ and this minimum will be the global minimum since if $|\beta| > R$ then $f_j(\beta) > f_j(0)$.

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman Actually when the vector space is over $\mathbb{R}$ it is true that $f_j$ is convex so the minimum is unique. Some intuition here is that $\{\alpha x_i + \beta x_j : \beta \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a line and that line has a unique point which is closest to the origin (which will minimize its norm). Also if you're using the standard norm then $\|\alpha x_i + \beta x_j\| = \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}$ is a convex function of $\beta$. When the norm isn't the standard one it requires some more computation to show it's convex.

Comment: When the field is $\mathbb{C}$ it should have similar properties to its real counterpart but I'm not sure if "convex" is the right word to use.

Comment: Thank you. I have to say, I never noticed that a norm is necessarily continuous!